# Android layouts for custom views

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a window with a custom view at the top, and three buttons at the bottom. I would like the view to take up the real estate which is left over after the buttons have been created. My layout XML is as follows

```
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff" >
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/CustomFrame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#ffffff" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"  />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"  />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clear"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"  />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I then add my custom view to the window with the code

```
  setContentView(R.layout.drawitwindow);
  FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.CustomFrame);
  mView = new MyCustomView(this);
  layout.addView(mView);
```

in the onCreate method.

However, the custom view takes up the whole screen! If I remove the code which adds the custom view to the frame, the button bar appears at the top of the window (as I would expect).

I've tried overriding the onMeasure method, adding

```
     super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

     int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
     int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
     this.setMeasuredDimension(parentWidth,parentHeight);
```

but this doesn't make any difference.

I've tried various combinations of layout width and height, and again that doesn't seem to make any difference.

All help will be very gratefully received...

Answer (score 0):

Change the FrameLayout android:layout_height to wrap_content.

Also add to the FrameLayout and to the Buttons' Linear Layout android:layout_weight="1.0".

I hope this helps.

Comment: Rui, thanks for the tip. That made things better, but didn't unfortunately solve the problem completely - the buttons now appear, but they have an incorrect (small) height and so the text doesn't show.

I browsed around a few more appends and found a solution which does work. Unfortunately, I can't post the new XML as I'm out of space! Basically, I use a relative layout at the top level, as specified in the question "how to put custom view above built in views in android"

I don't know why I didn't find this topic before; I spent several hours looking for a solution before I asked my question.

Comment: Yes, a relative layout is easier to use. If you played a bit with the layout_weight on each layout, it would work.

Comment: Thanks, Rui - I'll go back to the linear layout and play with the layout_weight as well; it all helps with understanding.